# Listing files in a given directory on Linux

Tags: c, linux, directory, scandir

I am using `scandir()` to list PNG images in a given directory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int file_select(const struct dirent *entry)
{
    struct stat st; 
    stat(entry->d_name, &st);
    return (st.st_mode & S_IFREG);       // This doesn't work
    /* return (st.st_mode & S_IFDIR); */ // This lists everything
}
int num_sort(const struct dirent **e1, const struct dirent **e2) {
    char* pch = strtok ((char*)(*e1)->d_name,".");
    char* pch2 = strtok ((char*)(*e2)->d_name,".");
    const char *a = (*e1)->d_name;
    const char *b = (*e2)->d_name;
    return atoi(b) > atoi(a);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n;

    n = scandir(".", &namelist, file_select, num_sort);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("scandir");/
} else {
    while (n--) {
        printf("File:%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
        free(namelist[n]);
    }
    free(namelist);
}
}
```

The problem is that the code above also lists:

```
.
..
```

which I want to get rid of. To do that, I have used:

```
return (st.st_mode & S_IFREG);
```

to list all regular files. However, this returns nothing, whereas `& S_IFDIR` returns everything (i.e. directories *and* files). How can I fix it?

Comment: You just have to check the name string. If it's `.` or `..`, return false.

Comment: `if( strcmp(namelist[n]->d_name, ".") && strcmp(namelist[n]->d_name, "..") )         printf("File:%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);` is what you want?

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thanks but I still don't understand why `S_IFREG` didn't work.

Comment: @BlueMoon Not exactly but I added something similar in the `file_select()`, so that `namelist` would contain only entries I want.

Comment: I don't see why `S_IFREG` shouldn't work. But this will exclude more files than you might want. All you want is to exclude `.` and `..` then a simple condition will suffice. `S_IFDIR` will also work (if you want to exclude all dirs).

Comment: Your code as it is [doesn't print](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4bc4d2ba89e6493) `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 0):

Try (st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG.

You need to perform the & operation with the file type bit field before comparing it to S_IFREG.

There are also macros defined for these types of operations, which you can find [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (I'll also list below)

```
       S_ISREG(m)  is it a regular file?

       S_ISDIR(m)  directory?           

       S_ISCHR(m)  character device?

       S_ISBLK(m)  block device?

       S_ISFIFO(m) FIFO (named pipe)?

       S_ISLNK(m)  symbolic link?  (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)

       S_ISSOCK(m) socket?  (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)
```